# SQLite select query with integer primary key in where clause returns empty result

Tags: c#, sqlite, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm saving some objects with ServiceStack.OrmLite to SQLite database with primary key "ID INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT". All works fine.

But when I trying to load objects by query "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE (ID = 112) OR (ID = 113)" the result is empty.

If I change where clause to "(ID+0 = 112) OR (ID+0 = 113)" there are 2 rows in result. 
When I explore database with sqlite command line tool I see that all records are here, column type is INTEGER, typeof(ID) for all rows returns "integer".
What might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try recreating the table using **INTEGER PRIMARY KEY** ... rather than **ID INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT** or **ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT**.

The way SQLite handles the ROWID is different depending on syntax.

Check out [SQLite Autoincrement](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) for more information.